# Webapp2 routing regex failing

Tags: regex, routes, webapp2

I've been having trouble getting webapp2 to recognise a path:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/welcome\?username=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})$', WelcomePage), # FAILS
    (r'/', MainPage),
    ], debug=True)
```

I inserted some prints in the calling function (MainPage) to check the regex:

```
            welcome_path = "/welcome?username=" + username
            print welcome_path   #debug stuff: check to if regex matches
            m = re.match(r'/welcome\?username=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})$', welcome_path)                     
            print m.groups(0)
            self.redirect(welcome_path) #
```

Based on the server log it looks ok:

```
INFO     2015-04-29 20:07:23,667 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1287
/welcome?username=fred  # printed by debug lines above
(u'fred',)              # indicates match and captured group
INFO     2015-04-29 20:07:34,588 module.py:788] default: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-04-29 20:07:34,614 module.py:788] default: "GET /welcome?username=fred HTTP/1.1" **404** 154
```

Regex from WSGIApplication (a) and inserted in calling function are identical - copy-pasted here:

```
r'/welcome\?username=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})$' # a
r'/welcome\?username=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20})$' # b
```

For completeness:

```
class WelcomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, username):
        self.response.write("<h1>Welcome, {}!</h1>".format(username))
```

But there's a 404 error... Why is the WSGIApplication failing to match the path?

(Note: this isn't production code - just an exercise from a MOOC on Udacity, whose forums have been down for a week...)

Comment: Please also post the `WelcomePage` class code.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because redirect triggers a GET request, which is matched according to the path: **after the hostname, but before the '?'**, not everything after the hostname as I'd assumed.

So this worked:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/welcome', WelcomePage),
    (r'/', MainPage),
    ], debug=True)


class WelcomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        if check_username(username) == "": # returns "" if no error
            self.response.write("<h1>Welcome, {}!</h1>".format(username))
        else:
            self.redirect('/')
```